# Only One Media Query Being Applied

Tags: wordpress, css, css-selectors, media-queries

So I have a child theme that I'm trying to make responsive, but one of the media queries won't apply at all - the one set to change the background of .single-column to orangered once the screen is smaller than 700px. The other two media queries work perfect. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this one media query isn't working and how i can fix it?

This is a child theme and the parent theme had media queries for the following screen sizes: 2500px, 1300px, 1100px, 1000px. None of these are being overridden by my code, but I'm curious as to if this has something to do with my problem, since the screen size I'm having trouble with isn't in the parent theme's set of media queries.

```
 /* 1100px */
 @media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    .mostrecent > ul {
      background-color: blue;
    }
 }

 /* 1000px */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .single_column {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
 }

 .right_column70 {
    order: 1;
    width: 100%;
 }

 .left_column30 {
    order: 2;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
 }

 .mostrecent > ul {
    display: flex;
 }
}

/* 700px 
This one doesn't work */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .single_column {
     background-color: red;
 }
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why it shouldn't work. Check it out:https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/4wca1s9k/. Most likely, you have another rule overriding the `background-color` property in your CSS, regardless of device width, with a stronger selector than 1 class. Use inspector to see where the current value is coming from.

Comment: Hmm how weird, I just checked the inspector and the only other place `background-color` is defined is in `body`. When I define it without the media query it applies fine.

Comment: In that case check very closely for any syntax error in the declaration ***before*** this one (syntax errors make following rules no longer apply, depending on what the error is). Also, check your markup for any validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Most lilkely there is a CSS rule in the main theme stylesheet for `.single_column` using a selector with a higher *CSS specifity* (you might wat to google that for more information). In that case the media query rule won't overwrite it due to its lower specifity.

You should check that `.single_column` element using the browser tools to see which CSS rule is applied to it.

If for example that rule has a selector like `main .container-1 div.wrapper > products .single_column`, you need to use that same selector (or an even more specific/complex one) for your own CSS rule in that media query.